# Problems locating Redmine database

Tags: database, postgresql, redmine

I have an active redmine but I can not find the database where it is running right now. It should be on PostgreSQL but the database where it should be running is empty. Does anybody have any idea how to check current database used by redmine?

Please let me know if you need any extra information.

Thank you

EDIT: Ok I know the database it is using. On the database.yml I have project_redmine but it is using the database project I dont know why. That database it is used by developers for the actual project. So that is getting me problems of course. I am unable to run it on the right DB (project_redmine) any ideas? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to do this. You need to get into rails console, that is:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

(Well depending on your environment you might need to change production for test or whatever)

Then run

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

And you will get something like this:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0x7ff679473020 @connection_parameters=["localhost", port, nil, nil, "database", "user", "pass"]
```

That worked for me. Now I need to figure out why I have those values... but that is a diferent story...

Answer (score 1):

Like any other Rails app, the database information is stored in the `config/database.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This files is populated  but that database is empty. Seems like is not using this file because even if I use a mysql DB there but I don't load in the bundle the pg gem I got an error saying that gem can not be found. It seems it is taking the info from other place rather than database.yml. Is this posible?

Comment: Did you accidentally start your app in `development` instead of `production`, or vice versa?

Comment: No, that is correct, I am running production